# Option for immediate output of rlang warnings

Tags: r, rlang

If I create a warning using the [rlang package](https://rlang.r-lib.org) inside a function, the warning is output after the function output:

```r
delayed_warning <- function() {
  rlang::warn("A warning")
  Sys.sleep(10)
  "A return value"
}

delayed_warning()
#> Warning: A warning
#> [1] "A return value"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In some circumstances it is useful to output warnings immediately, for example when the warning is to tell the user that a function might take a long time. If I were to use the base-R `warning()`, I could use `immediate. = TRUE` to output the warning immediately.

My question: is there a way to output immediately a warning created using `rlang::warn()`?

(This feels like the sort of thing that I should have been able to answer with a Google search, so I suspect I'm not searching for the right terms.)

Comment: Judging from the docs it doesn't seems possible to throw immediate warnings with rlang. But in your use case the problem could be resolved by using `rlang::inform()` which is not a warning, but might be enough to let the user know that the computation takes longer than expected.

Comment: `rlang::warn()` ultimately calls `base::warning()` so you could set the global warn option to be immediate inside your function and restore the default value on exit.  Obviously this would apply to any warning triggered while your function was running.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento thanks, but that doesn't work inside a package because modifying the user's environment is (rightly) not allowed by CRAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further digging I found a [GitHub issue requesting exactly this functionality](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/1546) in rlang. The issue has been closed with a note saying there is no plan to provide this.

Since outputting a warning immediately isn't possible using `rlang::warn()`, it seems the best workaround (as posted by [@TimTeaFan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9349302/timteafan) in a comment) is to instead use `rlang::inform()`, since messages are produced immediately by default:

```r
instant_message <- function() {
  rlang::inform("A message")
  Sys.sleep(10)
  "A return value"
}

instant_message()
#> A message
#> [1] "A return value"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that `rlang::warn` calls base R's `warning()` under the hood, as Ritchie Sacramento pointed out.

We can use this fact to alter the call of `rlang:warn` on the fly. This is some dirty function hacking, but it works.

We define a function `warn2` which:

1. takes `rlang::warn`
2. extracts the function `body()`
3. turns it into a list
4. gets the last line
5. turns the call into a list
6. appends `immediate. = TRUE` argument
7. turn this list into call
8. overwrite the original last line
9. overwrite the original function body
10. call the function

This approach does work, but it has two downsides.

First, you'd need to check prior versions of rlang if `rlang::warn` really ends with calling `warning()`. In a package just set the required rlang version to the version that starts using `warning()` in the last line.

Second, it is of course not guaranteed that future versions of rlang will still use base R's `warning()` in the last line. If at one point this changes your custom `warn2` function would not work anymore and we would probably need some error checks and workarounds for this.

All in all I'd say this kind of dirty function hacking is not a clean solution to your problem. But if you want to throw immediate warnings with rlang this is the way you could go. I have no idea if this kind of function hacking is allowed in a CRAN package, but I'd be curious to find out.

```r
warn2 <- function(msg) {
  f        <- rlang::warn
  f_bdy    <- body(f)   
  f_bdy_ls <- as.list(f_bdy)
  lst_line <- length(f_bdy_ls)
  warn_cl  <- f_bdy_ls[[lst_line]]
  warn_ls  <- as.list(warn_cl)
  warn_ls  <- append(warn_ls, list(immediate. = TRUE))
  
  f_bdy_ls[[lst_line]] <- as.call(warn_ls)
  
  body(f)  <- as.call(f_bdy_ls)
  f(msg)
}

delayed_warning <- function() {
  warn2("A warning")
  Sys.sleep(10)
  "A return value"
}

delayed_warning()
#> Warning: A warning
#> [1] "A return value"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>